# Google Cloud Platform Pub/Sub push empty POST data

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, push, google-cloud-pubsub

When I try to send a message in the cloud platform GUI (i.e. topic -> publish message on the [cloud platform topic page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topics/)) my endpoint PHP script is triggered, but the POST data is empty.

So all the permissions and domain verifications are in place. The topic and subscription both seem to be correct.

I found this [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331722/google-cloud-pub-sub-push-messages-empty-post) but

`json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);`

did nothing. I also tried

```
$content = null;
foreach( $_POST as $k => $v ){
// Just to see what any possible data might be
    $content .= "Key: $k, Value: $v\n";
}
$file = fopen( __DIR__ . '/log.txt', 'w') or die( 'Unable to open file!' );
fwrite( $file, $content );
fclose( $file );
return;
```

in the push endpoint URL. Same thing. Empty. So it seems that the POST body is empty and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was [removed in PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) even in earlier verisons, it required `always_populate_raw_post_data` in php.ini. As the answer you linked says, `$_POST` will not work.

Instead use:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```