# PHP get data from pubsub

Tags: php, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pub/sub project, and i want to use it in my PHP project, my topic is setup:[image]

I have a php script to serve this, msg.php:

```
$file = "text.txt";

$fp = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($_REQUEST));// tried $_POST, $_GET
fclose($fp);
```

But i can't get data from it, however script seems to be executed (i see it by changed date of txt file). I always end up with a **[]** in a text.txt, doesnt metter if notifications sended automaticaly or manualy by me through **publish message** option.
How can i get data from incoming pub/sub messages?

Solutions descriped in this questions doesnt work for me
[Google Cloud Platform Pub/Sub push empty POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616355/google-cloud-platform-pub-sub-push-empty-post-data)
[Google Cloud Pub/Sub Push Messages - Empty POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331722/google-cloud-pub-sub-push-messages-empty-post)

By this i mean replacing

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode($_REQUEST));
```

with

```
fwrite(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')_);
fwrite(json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA));
```

Comment: do you want to store your msg to a file and display from it

Comment: @MahfuzarRahman just store for now

Comment: what is the format of your data is your old msg storeable

Comment: @MahfuzarRahman i belive it;s json post https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#receiving_notifications

Comment: yes i have info that smth is sent to my server

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')` would be the right way to read & decode POSTed JSON data. If that doesn’t work as expected for you, then log what only `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns first of all.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the same problem, and following solution helped me. Hope this helps someone.

```
ob_start();

$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $rawData."\n";

$JSONObj = json_decode($rawData);

/*All sensitive data comes encoded in base64 and you need to decode that string, which gives another JSON String
*/
echo base64_decode($JSONObj->message->data);

$info = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fp, $info);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's json_encode function will output that open-and-close bracket "[]" when given an empty array.  There are 2 main possibilities that could be occurring.

1. It is possible that an empty array is being sent to your endpoint from pubsub.
2. Depending on your PHP version and configuration, the request contents may not come through $_REQUEST, $_POST or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variables.

I recommend using a function like the following to dump all the variables and environment settings to see if the expected data is coming into PHP at all:

```php
function PHPInfo2File($target_file) {
      ob_start();
      phpinfo();
      $info = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();

      $fp = fopen($target_file, "w+");
      fwrite($fp, $info);
      fclose($fp);
   }
```

If PHP is not receiving the data, the problem should be at the pubsub level.